# django -OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'registration_register.mobilexnumber' in 'field list'")

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to django as well as python. I am trying to create a registration and login form.The test registration page works with only the `username`, `email` and `password`. When i try to add `firstname`, `lastname` fields for my registration form there was no problem but when i added a new field `mobilexnumber`, when I go to the admin page, I get the following error

**OperationalError at /admin/registration/register/**

> (1054, "Unknown column 'registration_register.mobilexnumber' in 'field list'")

**models.py**

```
class Register(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobilexnumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    samplefld = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Register
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname','mobilexnumber', 'samplefld', )
    widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

Dont mind the `samplefld`. It was used for some error checking. Even without this field I get the same error.

I am using the following:

Django ver 1.9

Python ver 2.7.11

Pycharm ver 5.0.2

mySQL as database

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few searches, I found a somewhat ok solution. I followed all the steps given in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888046/django-1-8-create-initial-migrations-for-existing-schema). After that as @Eyal suggested I made the raw mySQL query from mySQL command line to add the particular column and it works!

Not the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

you should update your mysql db with the new column 'mobilexnumber'
(or run syncdb)

```
alter table register add column `mobilexnumber` varchar(50) NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've made changes to your Model without making the corresponding database schema changes. With Django 1.9, run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Here's the [documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#the-commands) and you'll see output similar to this:

```
$ manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'register':
  0002_register_mobilexnumber.py:
    - Add field mobilexnumber to register
$ manage.py migrate
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying register.0002_register_mobilexnumber... OK
```

Comment: I noticed that the column `mobilexnumber` field does not exist while `samplefld` column exists from mysql command line...Don't know why....