# Recreating a database for an existing django schema

Tags: django, postgresql

I've dropped my Postgres database by accident. Then as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29898483/1542475) I deleted the migration files but now can't execute the third step's command "python manage.py migrate --fake".

```
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. 
Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.


psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                         ^
```

I tried running "python manage.py migrate contenttypes" and "python manage.py makemigrations contenttypes --empty" but neither work.

Using django 1.9.5

Comment: You must run syncdb first !

Comment: @rakwouen: not on Django 1.9.5 they don't. `syncdb` is gone in 1.9, it's `manage.py migrate` replaces it. See ["Unknown command syncdb" running "python manage.py syncdb"](//stackoverflow.com/q/28685931)

Answer (score -1):

Synchronise your project first:
like this:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

when finish you can run: `python manage.py makemigrations` and last `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: `python manage.py syncdb` returns "Unknown command: 'syncdb'". I tried doing `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` but that returned the exact same thing as just "migrate"

Comment: wath django version you have ?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.9.5

Comment: If you have django 1.9 use makemigrations like this: python manage.py makemigrations; syncdb removed in 1.9 you must use makemigrations and migrate (python manage.py migrate). Don't forget add s in makemigrations command.

Comment: Yes I've done the standard makemigrations and then migrate. After makemigrations I get "no changes detected" and after migrate I get the contenttypes error like in my original post

Comment: `syncdb` was deprecated in Django 1.7, this answer was outdated when it was posted, and certainly is now. See ["Unknown command syncdb" running "python manage.py syncdb"](//stackoverflow.com/q/28685931)