# manage.py: error: no such option: --fake-initial

Tags: django, database-migration, django-1.7

I'm trying to [Create initial migrations for existing schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888046/django-1-8-create-initial-migrations-for-existing-schema) in Django 1.7 and I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29898483/2263683) solution from the above question.

But When I run

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

I get this error:

> Usage: manage.py migrate [options] [app_label] [migration_name]
>
> Updates database schema. Manages both apps with migrations and those
>   without.
>
> manage.py: error: no such option: --fake-initial

Considering that the question and answer are for Django 1.8, is it different how to do this in 1.7 version?

Answer (score 3):

The --fake-initial flag to migrate was added in Django 1.8. Previously, Django would always automatically fake-apply initial migrations if it detected that the tables exist.

See here in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial

Answer (score 0):

You're using Django 1.7 and that option was [added in 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate--fake-initial).