# Django Database - Complete Reset

Tags: django

This morning I have had a complete meltdown with my django progect :(  I have been fiddling with models and then got an error.  Cut a long story short I am now in a mess and absolutely nothing works.

The good news is that the content of the database is only test data so can all be lost.  I did a search on stackoverflow and found the following link:

[Django 1.8: Create initial migrations for existing schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888046/django-1-8-create-initial-migrations-for-existing-schema)

Below is a list of all my migration folders:

meta\migrations
straightred\migrations
allauth\account\migrations
allauth\socialaccount\migrations
allauth\socialaccount\providers\openid\migrations

That all makes sense but I do have 2 quick questions:

1) Do I remove the migrations for the project alluth? (a social network login app)
2) The allauth app also has some directories named: south_migrations.  Should these also be deleted?

Many thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated as I am now staring at a couple of months work not running because of a database hiccup :(

Comment: There's no need to remove the migrations. Just delete the database and then run the migrations again.

Comment: I did try that but I think I had corrupted / fiddled with my migrations so needed a completely clean slate I think.  Appreciate the response.  If I had not of been a wally I couldve used your idea.

Comment: what i did just now is i just delete the db.sqlite3 file and everything works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Delete all tables:

```
manage.py sqlclear
```

To Delete all Data:

```
manage.py flush
```

To recreate all the tables:

```
manage.py syncdb
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: These days I simply delete the db.sqlite3 file, which basically deletes the whole database, and then use 'manage.py migrate --run-syncdb' to recreate the database. I never use the commands on my answer so I wouldn't know if they have changed or not.

Comment: Who uses sqlite with a production Django system? Needless to say deleting a file won't work with postgresql or mysql. Still for what it' worth Django 2.2 and later support `manage.py sqlflush` which prints teh SQL for a complete database reset that you have to execute yourself, `manage.py flush` states explicitly that it is not a complete reset (in infer it clears the data but leaves the autoid sequencers but sqlflush explicty resets them to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your reverse migrations fail because the data doesn't fit the tables anymore. So another option is to first flush (delete) your data and then undo all your migrations.

So:

`./manage.py flush`

and then

`./manage.py migrate <appname> 0001_initial`

You can then delete or fix whatever migrations were broken, and try again with:

`./manage.py migrate`