# Django migration error while performing migration on existing schema

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, django-cms, django-1.11

I am upgrading my `django` application from `1.5` to `1.11`. I am upgrading 3rd party packages too. While upgrading `django-cms 2.4` to `3.5` I am facing some migration issues. I have an already existing mysql database. So after upgrading `django-cms`:

1) I deleted all the migration except `__init__.py` from `django-cms` migration folder.

2)Deleted data from `django_migration` data from my db using `delete from django_migrations;`.

3)Then I performed `python manage.py makemigration cms` and then `python manage.py migrate cms --fake`.

But while running application I am getting table `cms_urlconfrevision does not exist`.
Because some new tables are creating in new version of `django-cms`. As per my understanding no new tables will create while perform `--fake migration`. So I performed `python manage.py migrate` to create new tables but it showing error some table already exists. Please help me to get rid of this error.

Reference : [Django 1.8: Create initial migrations for existing schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888046/django-1-8-create-initial-migrations-for-existing-schema)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually delete/create table in the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Per the link you referenced, do it other way around:

> 3.Reset the migrations for the "built-in" apps: **python manage.py migrate --fake**
>
> 4. For each app run: **python manage.py makemigrations** . Take care of dependencies (models with ForeignKey's should run after their
>      parent model).

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
python manage.py makemigration cms
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```